# How can I clear the CommandLineArgs of an application from code?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

We have a 3rd party login dialog which will skip the login prompt if the login data is passed in via command line arguments. This is used when an application is launched from within the main 3rd party software.

The custom app I am writing should provide users with a button to change their login info, however since the app is launched with the login info provided in the command line args, the login dialog never appears when the button is clicked.

Is it possible to clear or reset `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` from the code?

**Edit**

I ended up simply restarting the application prior to startup if login info existed in the command line. This makes the 3rd party login dialog actually show up instead of automatically using the login info provided in the command line arguments.

I'm accepting [Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769540/how-can-i-clear-the-commandlineargs-of-an-application-from-code/7770558#7770558) because I feel it is the most complete answer to my question, although [Oded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769540/how-can-i-clear-the-commandlineargs-of-an-application-from-code/7769609#7769609) is also a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking can't be done in .NET because the `Environment` class caches the command line and there's no property accessor for setting it. (More correctly, the startup code caches the command line and `Environment.CommandLine` calls into the runtime to get that cached value.)

In a native Windows application, the `GetCommandLine()` API function returns a pointer to the command line that the operating system presented to the program. A program can call `CommandLineToArgvW` to parse the command line into the standard `argv` and `argc` parameters familiar to C and C++ programmers.

The `Environment` class uses something similar. When you call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, it accesses the `Environment.CommandLine` property and then calls the windows function `CommandLineToArgvW` to parse the command line. But `Environment.CommandLine` doesn't get its value from `GetCommandLine()`. Instead, the program gets the Windows command line at startup (by calling `GetCommandLine()`), and then saves it.

This is unfortunate, because you *can* modify the value that `GetCommandLine` returns, as demonstrated by this little snippet:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern IntPtr GetCommandLine();

static void DoIt()
{
    IntPtr pcmdline = GetCommandLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Environment.CommandLine = {0}", Environment.CommandLine);
    string realCmdLine = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pcmdline);
    Console.WriteLine("realCmdLine = {0}", realCmdLine);

    Console.WriteLine("** Modify command line");
    // Modify the command line
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ham and swiss on rye\0");
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pcmdline, bytes.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Environment.CommandLine = {0}", Environment.CommandLine);
    pcmdline = GetCommandLine();
    realCmdLine = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pcmdline);
    Console.WriteLine("realCmdLine = {0}", realCmdLine);
}
```

If you run that, you'll find that `Environment.CommandLine` returns the same string both times, whereas the second time you call `GetCommandLine`, you'll get back the string `ham and swiss on rye`.

Even if the above *did* work, there's no guarantee that it would solve your problem. The 3rd party control might parse the command line, cache the login information, and never parse the command line again.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation, although sadly it doesn't help me because the 3rd party dialog uses `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, which remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start a new instance of the application, providing the new credentials as arguments, and exit the current instance.

Comment: I don't want to re-launch a new instance because I don't want to lose the existing instance. The login provides not only the user's credentials for verifying access, but also what database their connected to. My main interest is to get the database they are connected to, and verify that they have access to that database.

Comment: @Rachel - I understand, but clearing out command line arguments is not possible. The application was launched with a specific command line, you can't change that...

Comment: So there's no way to clear command line args once an application has been launched with them?

Comment: @Rachel - Not as far as I know. That's why I suggested re-launching it. You _can_ parse the original command line and reuse portions of it.

Comment: I actually want to clear it completely so it prompts the user for new login info. I really don't like the idea of relaunching the program since then I lose the current visual state, but I also have to wait for everything to load again. I suppose it would only do that once though since after that there are no command line args so it would prompt the user like normal....

Answer (score 0):

Add additional command line argument(s) to indicate this secondary condition.  For example, an argument could be ShowLogin.  If true, then the command line arguments pre-fill the login dialog and the users could update there information as needed.   If false, then the arguments are used to auto log in without showing the dialog.

Comment: But it's a 3rd party login dialog that, presumably, the OP can't control in that way.

Comment: @Jim - Thx for the clarification, if they could change it on the other end, I think that would be optimal, otherwise I think Oded's solution is probably the best.